# How to change font with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, dreamweaver

Im working on my website and am trying to replicate a font I was using in Photoshop. The Font name is Trebuchet MS. Im using Dreamweaver CS5.5. I dont think there is a way to use HTML for this, but im pretty sure there is in CSS.
Thanks!

Comment: you can use `font-family` in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, ...;
```

in CSS. This will work only for users who have Trebuchet MS installed, which means pretty much all users with Windows and mostly not others. Others will see the text in some of the fonts you put in place of “...”, or in the browser’s default font.

If you want a cross-browser solution, you need to find a free font (or a font that is licensable for use as a web font) that suits your needs and use it as a web font via `@font-face` (there are loads of tutorials on this, some of them good).